# document.querySelector CHANGE event?

Tags: reactjs, jquery-selectors, jestjs

Is it possible to test an onChange event using document.querySelector inside of a Modal

Using jest and enzyme for react js file

```
  <Modal isOpen={this.state.quickFilterModalOpen} style={descriptionModalStyle}>
     <div>
        <div className='fullmodal'>
          <div id='close-modal' className='sidemodal_addnew_x' onClick={this.closeModal}>
            <FontAwesome name='xbutton' className='fa-times' />
          </div>
        </div> 
   <div className='advanced-search-modal-body'>
       <div className='advanced-search-modal-inner'>
        <label>First Name</label>
       <input  id='first-name-filter'onChange={(e) => {this.setState({advancedFilter: {...this.state.advancedFilter, FirstName: e.target.value}})}}  value={this.state.advancedFilter.FirstName}/>
```

Here is my test file
I have done so far with click events but not with Onchange
Trying to get the following onChange event to pass

```
it('Test click event on Modal : Save Button', () => {
   baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
   ReactModal.setAppElement('body');
   wrapper = mount(
     <ReactModal isOpen>
         <div className="fullmodal">
         some content
         </div>
     </ReactModal>,
    {attachTo: mountingDiv}
    );
   wrapper.setState({
    quickFilterModalOpen:true,
    advancedFilter:'test'

})
wrapper.update()
expect(wrapper.find('.fullmodal').exists()).toEqual(false);
expect(!!document.body.querySelector('.fullmodal')).toEqual(true);
document.querySelector("#first-name-filter").change(); //wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enzyme's simulate()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html)

```
wrapper.find('.fullmodal').simulate('change', { ...optionalMockEventDataToPass });
```

Comment: i tried that a few times, but it wont work,  Having a hard time testing Modal

Comment: @user9191 could you throw your example into a codepen/fiddle/sandbox to see where you're at and also clarify an assertion for after the change event that indicates the change worked as you expected (can just comment that in the code as well).